# Adding local dependenies in C# without absolute path

Tags: c#

My current specialization is TypeScript/NodeJS, but I know what each popular language has the package management including referencing to local dependency.

What the equivalent of `package.json` for the `ProjectName.csproj` of a C# project?

```json
{
    dependencies: {
        "local-one": "../foo/bar"
    }
}
```

For this question, it is important to not use the absolute paths because these paths will become unactual once other team members will clone the repository on his local computes while relative paths could be actual in mono repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a .csproj file, you have two common ways of specifying dependencies.  `<ProjectReference ...>` elements reference other C# projects (relative paths are fine).  `<PackageReference ...>` elements reference nuget packages (i.e. external libraries by name only - they will be stored in the global assembly cache (GAC) and no path needs to be specified.

If you are working with .NET Framework projects, external libraries may be specified by a combination of `<Reference ...>` elements in the .csproj file (again relative paths would be expected) and a packages.config file specifying the nuget packages.

Relative paths will be used automatically by most IDEs you might be using.  Generally you shouldn't need to edit the project file directly too often.

I'd recommend following some simple C# tutorials and examining the .csproj files you end up creating to try and understand them.

Best of luck working with C#.

**EDIT**
As requested, an example of a `<ProjectReference ...>`:
From a .NET Framework/old-style project:

```xml
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\path\to\MySecondProject.csproj">
      <Project>{1E14D605-3FD2-4AA7-8578-78944A8BB348}</Project>
      <Name>MySecondProject</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

The Guid is the identifier for the other project (you can find it in the other .csproj file).

From an SDK-style project:
`<ProjectReference Include="..\..\path\to\MySecondProject.csproj">`

Again, I will recommend that you use an IDE to modify your project, especially if you are working on .NET Framework projects.

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions?view=vs-2022#add-a-project-reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but `<ProjectReference Include="../../../MyLibrary" />` does not work and I did not find some examples. May I ask you to add the example of valid `ProjectReference` with relative path?

Comment: Thank you for the example! I accepted and upvoted your great answer.